# Find $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f^{-1}(x)}{\ln(x)}$, where $f(x)=e^x+x^3-x^2+x$, without L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

We have $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},f(x)=e^x+x^3-x^2+x$ and we need to evaluate $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f^{-1}(x)}{\ln(x)}$$

> There is an elegant way to solve this problem ?

Here is all my steps:

- My first ideea was to use squeeze theorem such that: $$\alpha\leq f^{-1}(x)\leq\beta$$

  $f(\ln(x))=x+\ln^3(x)-\ln^2(x)+ln(x)\ge x\Rightarrow\beta=\ln(x),\forall x>1$

> How can I find $\alpha$ such that $f( ? )\leq x,\forall x\in V$ where $V\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $(\exists)$ an open interval I such that $x\in I\subset V$ ?

**P.S.**: I know the method with L'Hospital's rule and absolutely is the easiest way to solve my problem, but I don't consider an "elegant way". I forgot to say that.

- What I want to prove in my demonstration is that $\frac{\alpha}{\ln(x)}\leq\frac{f^{-1}(x)}{\ln(x)}\leq\frac{\beta}{\ln(x)}$ and if we see the upper bound $\frac{\beta}{\ln(x)}\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$

So what I have to do is to find $\alpha$ such that $\frac{\alpha}{\ln(x)}\to 1$

Comment: Typo spotted! $n\to\infty$??

Comment: Can you use L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal was a minor error, I don't think it was the problem

Comment: @KittyL I don't want use L'Hospital's rule, I know the method, I want some help in my demonstration

Comment: The title is "I need some help in my solution" so don't avoid the subject

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do? The intuition should be that the limit exists and equals $1$ -- your upper bound meanwhile diverges for $x \to \infty$

Comment: gt6989b why you say that the upper bound is diverges ? because $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\beta}{\ln{x}}=1$ and what I want to try is to prove that $\frac{\alpha}{\ln(x)}\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$

Comment: gt69689b now is better of what I want to do ?

Answer (score 6):

Substitue $x=f(y)$ and observe that $x \to \infty \Leftrightarrow y \to \infty$. Thus, your limit equals

$$ \lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(f(y))}{\ln(f(y))}=\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y}{\ln(e^y+y^3-y^2+y)}.$$

Comment: user can you give me a helping hand in my demonstration ? I know your method, and absolutely is the easiest way to solve the problem

Comment: @Lucas I'm sorry, but I can't see how to finish your approach.

Comment: How can I prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f^{-1} (x) = \infty$ ?

Comment: @Lucas I suggest you look at the graph of the function, as well as the fact that the graph of the inverse is the reflection across the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Prove that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f^{-1}(x) = \infty$$ and note that L'Hospital's rule applies. Now you need to differentiate $f^{-1}(x)$, how do you do that?

Comment: gt6989b thanks for edited, can you give me a helping hand in my demonstration ?

Comment: How can I prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f^{-1} (x) = \infty$ ?

Comment: @Lucas $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f^{-1}(x) = \infty$$ is equivalent to $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$$ (just take $f(\cdot)$ of both sides)

Answer (score 2):

Squeezing works. For any $\varepsilon>0$, for any $x$ big enough $f(x)$ is between $e^x$ and $e^{(1+\varepsilon)x}$.

That gives that for any $t$ big enough  $f^{-1}(e^t)$ is between $\frac{t}{1+\varepsilon}$ and $t$, so the limit is $\color{red}{1}$ by setting $x=e^t$.